# Comparing 2 fields using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I am trying to compare 2 fields(double) using python. I want to round to the nearest 10th and flag those with a "1" that are not equal. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
def Qcontrol(old, new):
  FieldA = math.round(old,1)
  FieldB = math.round(new,1)
  if FieldA == FieldB:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1

Return=
 Qcontrol(!old!, !new!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove `math.` before the `round` function.

```
def Qcontrol(old, new):
    FieldA = round(old,1)
    FieldB = round(new,1)
    if FieldA == FieldB:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Reference for the built-in function [round()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining a function, you can do something like this...

```
0 if round(!FieldA!,1) == round(!FieldB!,1) else 1
```